# How to create unique `id` attributes in AngularJS ng-repeat repeaters

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm seeing this in our templates. They say it's so the code can be tested but it still seems wrong to me:

```
<tr ng-repeat="comp in collection">
    <td>
        <span id="someId">{{comp.someText}}</span>
    </td> 
    ....
```

I'm thinking we should be using name instead.

Comment: **No.** There's no harm to doing it that way.

Comment: From [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute): The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. As for me - having the same value for all the `span` elements in repeater doesn't make any sense even for testing purposes.

Comment: Browsers use the `id` attribute for scrolling for urls with hash `#` fragments. Having a html document with duplicate `id` attributes is like having a book with duplicate page numbers.

Answer (score 4):

If you really need unique IDs inside the repeater, try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="comp in collection">
    <td>
        <span id="someId{{$index}}">{{comp.someText}}</span>
    </td>
```

So if, for instance, you need to link labels to inputs in the ngRepeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="comp in collection">
    <td>
        <label for="field{{$index}}">{{field.label}}</label>
        <input type="text" id="field{{$index}}" ng-model="field.value" />
    </td>
```

This approach is especially useful if you need to have check boxes with clickable labels inside the ngRepeat.